# Why is dictionary with only keys len zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make dictionary that are made of only keys. I will populate the value latter. I don't want set. I want key and value data structure. I have variable called legends that has len of 4.

```
print("len = ",len(my_legends)) # prints 4
plot_param=dict()
plot_param.fromkeys(my_legends)
print("dic len = ", len(plot_param)) # prints 0, I was hoping it to be 4. 

for key in plot_param:
  print("key == ") # cannot print values at all.
```

I was planning to loop over the keys and populate its values now I cannot loop at all.

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary with only keys.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Yes, that's a set  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
plot_param.fromkeys(my_legends)
```

You probably wanted:

```
plot_param = dict.fromkeys(my_legends)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you